# Can We Skip htmlspecialchars for Trusted Authors in PHP Web Pages

Tags: php, html, security, xss

I understand that we use the `htmlspecialchars` function to Convert special characters to HTML entities.

However, is it ok to skip this function if the content author is trusted? By trusted, I mean a trustworthy person or website creator who writes HTML directly in PHP files for static pages and understands what output it would produce.

Or where we don't accept any user input.

Examples:

```
<?= '<p>Users aren\'t allowed to do this.</p>' ?>

<p><?= 'You aren\'t authorized.' ?></p>

<?php if (someFunction()): ?>
You aren't authorized.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Instead of `<p><?= htmlspecialchars('Users aren\'t allowed to do this.') ?></p>`

The same question is for `htmlentities` function. Any security risk behind the scenario.

Comment: Generally, this is considered a bad practice, even if the writer is you yourself. The real question is, why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Ease of writing and sometimes one forgets to place the converter function in between a lot of HTML.

Comment: There are ways of avoiding doing this without typing everything out. You can use .htaccess to pre-include a standard.php file at the start of all your PHP files, using that you can create a function that re-renders, all page's HTML to be converted so that you don't need to use `htmlspecialchars` repeatedly. This is one of the ways this is done. For the implementation of this, Google will be your best friend.

Comment: The code writer cannot predict in advance who's going to use the site, so this doesn't sound feasible. Just get into the habit of using it, and review your code periodically (or get someone else to review it) to ensure you haven't missed any necessary usages anywhere. There's really no good reason to skip using it.